# IO.Ports exception throw and retry loop

Tags: c#, exception, arduino

I've been lurking here for a while, and have learned a ton just poking through questions.  I'm pretty stumped on something, though. I'm using [C#](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_Sharp_%28programming_language%29), and I'm trying to use IO.Ports to communicate with a USB device.

I've got code working that assumes the correct serial port, but sometimes my device winds up on a different port when plugged in, and I'd like to be able to run my code without having to change one variable and recompile. So, I want the code to poll the user for a port number, try to open the port, catch IOException when the port name's wrong, and re-poll until a valid port is given.

This is what I have so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO.Ports;

namespace USBDev1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String portname = "COM";
            SerialPort port = new SerialPort();
            port.BaudRate = 9600;
            bool loopthing = true;

            while (loopthing == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Which port?");
                portname = "COM" + Console.ReadLine();
                try
                {
                    port.PortName = portname;
                    port.Open();
                    loopthing = false;
                }
                catch (System.IO.IOException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Didn't work, yo");
                    throw (e);
                }
            }

            // Body code
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: And the question is...?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you are asking, but I think you should list the available ports before choosing one. The following code may work; it compiles, but it is not tested.

This is also not a good way to do it. A better way would be to list the ports before you plug in your device, then list the ports again to see the new port that showed up after you plugged in the device.

```
SerialPort port;

bool isCorrectPortFound = false;

// Try different ports until a device reacts when a character is written to it
while (!isCorrectPortFound)
{
    // Get all open ports
    string[] ports = SerialPort.GetPortNames();

    // Menu choice for a port to select
    char portSelect = '0';

    // Write the port names to the screen
    foreach (string s in ports)
    {
        portSelect++;
        Console.Write(portSelect);
        Console.Write(". ");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
    }

    Console.WriteLine();

    Console.Write("Select from port 1 to " + portSelect.ToString() + " > ");
    int selectedPort = (Console.Read()) - '0'; // Character value of 1 to ...

    try
    {
        // Assume selectedPort is a valid integer, set baud, etc. as per your choice.
        port = new SerialPort(ports[selectedPort] /* COMportBaudRate, 
                                                     COMportParity, 
                                                     COMportDataBits, 
                                                     COMportStopBits */);

        // OK, port is open, write to the device. The device 
        // must respond visually, blinking a LED or something.
        port.Write("A");

        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.Write("Did the device get your message? (y n) > ");
        int a = (Console.Read()) - 'a';

        if (a + 'a' == 'y')
            isCorrectPortFound = true;
        else
        {
            port.Close();
            port = null;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // Display a message box, exit, etc.
    }
}

// Do other stuff
```

Comment: Thanks, user*.  I think I've figured out what I did wrong with my approach.  I put a throw in the catch line because my understanding was that throw would *discard* the error.  Instead, once I caught the error I was worried about, I just immediately made a new one.  My code works like I was intending, now.